# com.sun.corba class not found in Java 7 update 67

Tags: java

While testing HPSA (HP Server Automation plugin) on jdk 1.7u67, it is throwing error but it is running fine with jdk 1.7u21.

```
Error:- 

Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.LogStrings bundle
    at java.util.logging.Logger.setupResourceInfo(Logger.java:1534) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:267) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
```

Comment: A class is missing. The error message seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: But I am not able to check if the class LogStrings is deprecated in jdk1.7u67.Is there any other class which can be used as the replacement for the same in jdk1.7u67

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JDK [bug 8021257](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8021257) addresses some security concerns with programs accessing classes and packages under `com.sun.corba.se.**`.  This bug was *backported* to Java 7 update 51 in [bug 8027797](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8027797), and documented in the release notes:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u51-relnotes-2085002.html

> The JDK internal package com.sun.corba.se and its sub-packages have been added to the restricted package list and therefore cannot be used directly when running with a security manager.
>
> Workaround:
>   Applications running with a security manager that make direct use of classes in these JDK internal packages, need to adjust their security policy to grant access. See [Java Security Policy Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html) documentation.

Comment: Thanks William.  So, the same com.sun.corba.se.* was not added to the restricted package list in update 21, it has been added to restricted package list from update 51 onwards.

Comment: @William Price, i'm getting this error when running servlet in JBoss. It is working fine when im running it in Tomcat. Used same JDK in both cases.

Comment: @Uday it's not just about the JVM. Just a guess, but might JBoss have a [default security policy](https://docs.jboss.org/jbosssecurity/docs/6.0/security_guide/html/chap-Java_EE_Security_Manager.html) that enables a security manager whereas Tomcat does not enable a manager by default?